# How to verify fingerprint wsq format?

Tags: vb.net, fingerprint

I have fingerprint stored in my database with .wsq format,then i want to create login system with vb.net. How to verify if user finger is match or not ?

Comment: wsq is the fingerprint _image_. You need to extract a _template_ from it. At login, also extract a template from user's _live_ fingerprint image. Now compare the two templates. There are SDKs that enable you to do the extraction and compare the templates.
Your fingerprint scanner might have come with such an SDK. I do not know of any (free) SDKs for vb.net. (My work is with only C and Java). However, there is a [limited free version of the Verifinger SDK](https://www.neurotechnology.com/download.html#megamatcher_verifinger_verilook_verieye_sdk_trial), and it has examples for VB.NET.

Comment: 've tried that, but I haven't found a way to convert wsq to jpg using vb.net
Is there another way besides using java?

Comment: You do not have to use java. Your question is about you verifying fingerprints. What you actually compare, are _not_ the fingerprint images. WSQ and jpg are images (pictures). You need to extract _templates_ from the images. The easiest way to do that, is to use some fingerprint  SDK. I mentioned an example of such SDKs (there are really many), and it has examples of how to extract and match using VB.

Comment: By the way, if your question is "how convert wsq to jpg using vb.net", I suggest that you edit the question. Since similar questions have been asked  before and answers provided, some of which could answer your question, we could then simply refer to those answers.